# Login is now through terminal

Tags: boot

Ever since I rebooted my computer, ElementaryOS has no splash screen and instead loads into a "terminal". It tells me I need to log in, and once I do I only have access to a "terminal". (It's not a true terminal like URxvt, but instead just a black and white command line).

I have been messing around with i3 and its counterparts for a couple of days now. Nothing has been wrong with it, from what I can tell. I have been messing around with ~/.Xresources, and I put a xrandr command in some (I have no idea where, sorry) .conf file to change my display refresh rate to 144hz.

When I turned my computer off the last time it went directly to a black "underscore" screen instead of turning off completely. I had to turn off the computer manually.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your session manager (elementary uses Pantheon) has failed. When you login to the terminal, do you see anything in journalctl that would raise eyebrows?

If nothing's there, there's some troubleshooting steps at the bottom of their [git page here](https://github.com/elementary/greeter)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you have the same problem, but what I did in order to successfully return to the graphics interface was to reinstall lightdm.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall lightdm
```

You can try before this to reconfigure it also by typing

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```